# I have project A and converted as JAR ,when tried to use in project B not seeing any packages and not able to access

Tags: java, maven

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn63x.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k2VC.png)I have used maven plugin in eclipse so I dont see any setting.xml even I tried by adding manually setting.xml.

What I am missing please correct me with In details step.

[My pom is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k2VC.png)

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>demo</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>SOA_API_Automation</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <systemPath>{jar/path}</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the settings.xml which is user-specific configuration for Maven, that is not present inside the POM. It's present in ~/.m2/settings.xml. For more details refer the [maven doc](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.1/maven-settings/settings.html)